# Azure DataBricks performance

Tags: azure-databricks

My requirement was to process approx 1TB of data stored in Azure container.The container contains millions of json files which are multi part in nature .

For this i was using HdInsight which was able to process the data in 45 mins approx :

Worker Nodes (1-4)autoscale - 16 cores 112 gb
Headnodes-2 - 4 cores 28gb

we planned to migrate to Azure Databricks Spark cluster

configuration of cluster used

Worker Nodes (4-10) autoscale - 8 cores 56gb - memory optimized
Head nodes - 4 cores 28gb

But this keeps running for more then 2.5 hrs but still the process was not completed, and i can see it used 4 worker nodes to the maximum but does not scale up to leverage the remaining worker nodes to speed up the process.

Can any one help if i am doing something wrong here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the Task **Type** you have mentioned while creating the Task?

[image]

In the Type drop-down, select **Notebook**, **JAR**, **Spark Submit**, **Python**, or **Pipeline**.

> If you have chosen Spark Submit then autoscaling isn't supported.

For autoscaling, you need to choose other options.

Additionally, autoscaling behaves differently depending on whether it is **optimized** or **standard** and whether applied to an all-purpose or a job cluster.

I suggest you to go through the official document on [cluster size and autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#cluster-size-and-autoscaling) to get better insights about the same.

Comment: @UtkarshPal-MIT Below are the details :

ClusterMode- Standard, all purpose job cluster, type-NoteBook

Comment: i am getting some errors which i ahve attached to the original post , can you please take a look